# C# struct by-ref

Tags: c#, .net, struct, ref

Is there any way in C# to be able to do this:

```
map.player.x = 5;
```

while keeping `player` of type `Point` (or silently convertible to one) and still be able to check the value for correctness when doing the assignment?

To be clearer:

- `Point` is a struct defined by the C#/.net standard libraries and is passed by value.
- Making a wrapper class and implementing all of `Point`'s methods as call-throughs to `Point` is long and tedious.
- Having a wrapper class with nothing but an implicit coversion to/from `Point` will not allow the above. It would have to be written as `(Point)(map.player).x`, which is clumsy.

Comment: Should that be X (not x)? The standard Point has X and Y, and c# is fussy about case...?

Comment: Also, is player a property or a field? Presumably a field here? (else it wouldn't compile, IIRC)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes, it should be X. If it is a property or a field is what I am debating. I want to get the advantages of both.

Comment: Does your `Point` really have to have anything to do with the "standard" `Point` in the .NET libraries? Mutable struct are evil. Avoid them unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: @Jason It is just more convenient then implementing all the operators myself.

Comment: @baruch: Not at the expense of running into trouble like this. A `Point` for whatever your purposes are is *trivial* to implement.

Comment: @Jason What trouble? Everyone seems to shudder at this question, but I don't see why?

Comment: Because you're using a mutable struct. It's getting you into trouble already! It's going to get you into more trouble. Avoid, avoid, avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you right, you seem to want to get some flexibility by defining type-conversions. That won't go very far.

Avoid mutable structs (value types). `struct Point` is an unfortunate leftover from the old Win32 API.

So aim for `map.player = new Point(5, map.player.y);`

Comment: @baruch: Everything :) Seriously, search for "evil mutable struct" and you'll find lots of opinions, for and against. Mostly, you end up with awkward situations like this, and unexpected behaviour in other situations.

Answer (score 4):

No. Either `player` is a *variable*, in which case you don't get any chance to verify the change during the assignment, or `player` is a *property*, in which case the expression `map.player` is categorized as a *value* and you're not allowed to set the `x` part (as it would be usless).

I would suggest you create a method, so you can call:

```
map.SetPlayerX(5);
```

... or you make changing the `x` value part of a larger operation which is owned by the `Player` class. That's likely to be a more OO approach - *usually* if you find yourself wanting to do something like this, it's worth taking a look at the design and responsibilities.

Answer (score 1):

## 1

What about assigning both coordinates at the same time?

```
map.player = new Point(5, 7);
```

Now you can have the validation logic inside of the player property.

---

## 2

Do you really need to implement all the stuff of `System.Drawing.Point`? It should not be all too difficult to implement your own version with only the things you really need. There is not much logic in `Point`.

Answer (score 1):

Some people would suggest using a class type to hold the X and Y values.  I am leery of that approach, and would suggest that in many cases the semantics obtained by exposing `player` as a field would be much cleaner (though I'm unclear why `map` has a member called `player`.  If an `map` is reference to `MapType`, and instance of `MapType` has a field of struct type `player`, with a field `x` of type integer, it is clear that a change to `map.player.x` will affect one instance of `MapType`.  Also, saying `map1.player = map2.player;` will copy the fields from `map2.player` to `map1.player`.  By contrast, if `player` were of a class type and one did `map1.player = map2.player; map1.player.x = 5;`, that would affect both `map1` and `map2`.

The question of whether to use a mutable struct versus a mutable class is pretty straightforward, but the notion of "If it's mutable make it a class" is just plain wrong.  Simply ask yourself, given:

```
  thing1 = thing2;
  thing1.x = 5;
```

would you want the second statement to affect the value of `thing2.x`?  If yes, use a class.  If no, use a struct.

BTW, abother pattern to consider if you don't want your map type to expose `player` as a field would be to have it expose an ActOnPlayer method:

```
  public delegate ActionByRef<T>(ref T p);
  public delegate ActionByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);

  public void ActOnPlayer(ActionByRef<playerType> proc;)
  {
    proc(ref _player);
  }
  public void ActOnPlayer<T>(ActionByRef<playerType,T> proc, ref T param;)
  {
    proc(ref _player, ref param);
  }
... sample usage:
  map.ActOnPlayer((ref playerType it, ref int theParam) ->
    {it.x = theParam;}, someIntVariable);
```

Note that the latter approach would look something like using a closure, but unlike using a closure it would not generate any new temporary heap objects, and would thus not create any pressure on the garbage collector.